# Does this type of question count as "getting outdated quickly"?

Tags: discussion

[Current status of the UA Revised Ranger](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112616/current-status-of-the-ua-revised-ranger)

> **Does that Sourcebook exist yet?** If not, have the devs given an update or told us their intentions?

The bolded question seems similar to the reason we frown on question about shopping recommendation: they get outdated quickly.

When this type of question asked, it might or might not have been released yet, but some time in the future (like 6 months after), the correct answer might change.

**Is this type of question okay?**

Answer (score 8):

I think this is OK.

It is effectively a content identification question: “Surely this content exists but I don't know where to find it.” However, as part of the question we're also acknowledging the possibility it might not actually exist yet.

We've yet to discuss as a community whether we should support questions that ask about release dates. However, I think this question is OK to keep open, as it doesn't fit the pattern of those questions: it's not certain it's going to be obsolete, only the answers can really tell us that.